# Spree display only selected taxons on sidebar for different pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, taxonomy, spree

Hi I am new to spree and rails as well. please, help me with this.

I want to show selected taxons on sidebar for a page.
lets say my taxon structure is this

> ```
> Dresses
>    -Party
>       -sub category
>    -Casual
>       -sub category
>       -sub category
>    -Formal
>
> Pants
>    -Party
>    -Casual
>    -Formal
> Shirts
>    -Party
>    -Casual
>    -Formal
> ```

so when i am in `*www.host.com/t/pants*`

I want to show only

> ```
> Pants
>    -Party
>    -Casual
>    -Formal
> ```

in sidebar and hide all other taxon trees.

Please, help me in this.

the partial code is here which displays all taxonomies

```
<nav id="taxonomies" class="sidebar-item" data-hook>

  <% get_taxonomies.each do |taxonomy| %>

    <h6 class='taxonomy-root'><%= t(taxonomy.name.singularize) %></h6>


    <%= taxons_tree(taxonomy.root, @taxon, Spree::Config[:max_level_in_taxons_menu] || 1) %>

  <% end %>

</nav>
```

Comment: I need your help for setup same taxonomy structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current taxon selected (ex. www.host.com/t/pants) is available from

```
@searcher.properties[:taxon]
```

This is the pants taxonomy object, you can compare it to filter get_taxonomies results.

So I guess you could do something like :

```
<% get_taxonomies.select{|t| @searcher.properties[:taxon].nil? or t.id == @searcher.properties[:taxon].id }.each do |taxonomy| %>
```

But this won't work when you are in subcategories (ex. /t/pants/party)

Seems like there was an .ancestors method in earlier Spree version but now its gone so I guess there is still a quick way to check taxons ancestors but I haven't found how exactly.

Complete solution would be something like this :

```
<% get_taxonomies.select{|t| @searcher.properties[:taxon].nil? or t.ancestors.includes( @searcher.properties[:taxon].id) }.each do |taxonomy| %>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @jpdoyle for his help.

comparing

```
taxonomy.root
```

with each instance of

```
(@searcher.properties[:taxon]).ancestors.collect { |ancestor| seo_url(ancestor)}
```

solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

From Spree 3.7 the original method is as below and we can override `@taxonomies` variable value:

```
def show
  @taxon = Taxon.friendly.find(params[:id])
  return unless @taxon

  @searcher = build_searcher(params.merge(taxon: @taxon.id, include_images: true))
  @products = @searcher.retrieve_products
  taxonomies = Spree::Taxonomy.includes(root: :children)
  @taxonomies = taxonomies.select { |t| t.id == @taxon.taxonomy_id }
end
```

So we can select only those taxonomies which are actually associated with the selected taxon.